nfs mount fails - access denied by server while mounting (null)
get error trying to mount nfs from a client at ip address 192.168.1.7:
# mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp 10.24.69.1:/home/nfs /home/nfs
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting (null)

I find the '(null)' odd.  Trying nfsvers=3, nfsvers=4.0, mountvers=3, mountvers=4.0 give same result.
I can ping 10.24.69.1 from 192.168.1.7, so routing is working correct?
# ping 10.24.69.1
PING 10.24.69.1 (10.24.69.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.24.69.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=20.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.24.69.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=20.9 ms

And I can telnet to ports 111 and 2049 from 192.168.1.7, so no firewall issue correct?
# telnet 10.24.69.1 111
Trying 10.24.69.1...
Connected to 10.24.69.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

^\Connection closed by foreign host.
# telnet 10.24.69.1 2049
Trying 10.24.69.1...
Connected to 10.24.69.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.

showmount from 192.168.1.7 shows the fs is listed:
# showmount -e 10.24.69.1
Export list for 10.24.69.1:
/home/nfs 10.24.69.2/32,192.168.1.0/24

ssh to 10.24.69.1 works and shows I am coming from 192.168.1.7:
# ssh 10.24.69.1
Welcome to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-45-generic x86_64)
...
root@...:~# env|sort
...
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.7 48144 22
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.7 48144 10.24.69.1 22
...

Also odd, tcpdump on the server shows no activity, like the client doesn't even try, when doing the mount command.  It DOES show activity when doing those other commands (ping, telnet 111, telnet 2049, showmount), so it is not a routing or firewall issue as far as I can tell.  And so the server isn't even getting to the point of checking /etc/exports.
I CAN do the nfs mount from a client with ip address 10.24.69.2 and all is well.  tcpdump has plenty to dump, so seems the server is basically functioning.
But again the 192.168.1.7 client isn't even sending a packet to the server for the mount, so there isn't anything for the server to reject.  Is there a client-side config file for mount?  It is Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy.
Thanks for help.

never mind, desperate attempt of rebooting the client fixed it.  go figure.
